# ng-change blanking out dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have this drop down setup like this:

```
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="dataType" id="dataType"
                        ng-model="dataTypes"
                        ng-change="typeCheck()">
                    <option ng-repeat="option in dataTypes" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

In my controller I have this function:

```
        $scope.typeCheck = function () {
            alert($scope.dataTypes);
        };
```

After this function is called, sometimes my list disappears!  I say sometimes as because it is only on certain elements that get called.

This is my array that gets loaded into the dropdown:

```
    $scope.typeArrays = function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.dataTypes = [];
        vm.dataTypes = [
              { id: 'bigint', name: 'bigint' },
              { id: 'binary', name: 'binary' },
              { id: 'bit', name: 'bit' },
              { id: 'char', name: 'char' },
              { id: 'date', name: 'date' },
              { id: 'datetime', name: 'datetime' },
              { id: 'datetime2', name: 'datetime2' },
              { id: 'datetimeoffset', name: 'datetimeoffset' },
              { id: 'decimal', name: 'decimal' },
              { id: 'float', name: 'float' },
              { id: 'image', name: 'image' },
              { id: 'int', name: 'int' },
              { id: 'money', name: 'money' },
              { id: 'nchar', name: 'nchar' },
              { id: 'ntext', name: 'ntext' },
              { id: 'numeric', name: 'numeric' },
              { id: 'nvarchar', name: 'nvarchar' },
              { id: 'real', name: 'real' },
              { id: 'smalldatetime', name: 'smalldatetime' },
              { id: 'datetimeoffset', name: 'datetimeoffset' },
              { id: 'smallint', name: 'smallint' },
              { id: 'smallmoney', name: 'smallmoney' },
              { id: 'sql_variant', name: 'sql_variant' },
              { id: 'text', name: 'text' },
              { id: 'time', name: 'time' },
              { id: 'tinyint', name: 'tinyint' },
              { id: 'uniqueidentifier', name: 'uniqueidentifier' },
              { id: 'varbinary', name: 'varbinary' },
              { id: 'varchar', name: 'varchar' }
        ];
    }
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8m277gb/5/) of my code.

Comment: Something seems to be missing here.  Are you using controller-as syntax?    It's confusing to be using the name dataTypes to reference both the array of choices (in the object vm) and as the result of the selection (in the $scope), but I don't see how the option list is ever being populated -- that ng-repeat should be "option in typeArrays.dataTypes" if you are using controller-as syntax (which your controller implies).  Can you give a more complete view of your code?  Perhaps a fiddle?

Comment: you are mixing $scope and `this`. Not to mention that the `this` you are using is the function. Your controller model structure is incorrect. The view is set up for `$scope` so use that

Comment: @Beartums - I added a fiddle as you requested.  The bindings don't work but you can see the controller code.

Comment: @charlietfl - It seems like I'm doing this incorrectly.  I'm interested in my code being correct.  Can you please take a look at my fiddle and let me know exactly what I'm doing wrong and how it should be?

Comment: @charlietfl - I changed my array to use $scope.dataTypes and the bindings still work but the list disappears when some items are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, there was a little misconception about the models but this way, you set a `dataType` using `ng-model` and `ng-change` alerts the chosen dataType.

```
$scope.dataType = null;
 $scope.dataTypes = [
              { id: 'bigint', name: 'bigint' },
              { id: 'binary', name: 'binary' },
              { id: 'bit', name: 'bit' },
              { id: 'char', name: 'char' },
              { id: 'date', name: 'date' },
              { id: 'datetime', name: 'datetime' },
              { id: 'datetime2', name: 'datetime2' },
              { id: 'datetimeoffset', name: 'datetimeoffset' },
              { id: 'decimal', name: 'decimal' },
              { id: 'float', name: 'float' },
              { id: 'image', name: 'image' },
              { id: 'int', name: 'int' },
              { id: 'money', name: 'money' },
              { id: 'nchar', name: 'nchar' },
              { id: 'ntext', name: 'ntext' },
              { id: 'numeric', name: 'numeric' },
              { id: 'nvarchar', name: 'nvarchar' },
              { id: 'real', name: 'real' },
              { id: 'smalldatetime', name: 'smalldatetime' },
              { id: 'datetimeoffset', name: 'datetimeoffset' },
              { id: 'smallint', name: 'smallint' },
              { id: 'smallmoney', name: 'smallmoney' },
              { id: 'sql_variant', name: 'sql_variant' },
              { id: 'text', name: 'text' },
              { id: 'time', name: 'time' },
              { id: 'tinyint', name: 'tinyint' },
              { id: 'uniqueidentifier', name: 'uniqueidentifier' },
              { id: 'varbinary', name: 'varbinary' },
              { id: 'varchar', name: 'varchar' }
        ];

    $scope.colOptions= [];
    $scope.colOptions= [
          { id: '1', name: 'identity(1,1)' },
          { id: '2', name: 'constraint' }
    ];

    $scope.typeCheck = function () {
        alert($scope.dataType);
    };
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5extmuqg/

Answer (score 1):

@webdad3, cool. thanks for the fiddle.

This can be fixed with a couple of small changes.  `vm.datatypes` (in your function) should become `$scope.dataTypes`.  ANd the `ng-model` in your select should be `dataType`, NOT `dataTypes`.  Lastly, in `typeCheck()`, also refer to `$scope.dataType` (singular).

the vm. notation is usually used when you want to use `controller-as` syntax rather than $scope.  Since you're using $scope, just stick with that.  And the ng-model for the <select> element should be the object you want to set, not the object providing the list of options.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beartums/qy94ttxy/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Also, to get the fiddle to work with Angular, change the javasript options for LOAD TYPE to be 'no wrap - in <body>'